# MenuBar sometimes shows icon and sometimes not

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I am trying to put an actionBar with two icons (one going to the main activity, and the other one going the previous one)

The thing is that I have this as XML being used as menu:

```
<item android:id="@+id/Main_App"
    android:title="Main"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>

<item android:id="@+id/back_App"
    android:title="Back"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_back"/>
```

And the code for using it:

@Override

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Main_App) {
        Intent getNewMessageAct = new Intent(this,UpLinksActivity.class);
        startActivity(getNewMessageAct);
        finish();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.back_App){
        Intent getNewMessageAct = new Intent(this,NewMessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(getNewMessageAct);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I always use the same menu, and sometimes icons fits on the ActionBar and sometimes not. I don't get why it is happening.

It's nothing to do about the size because it has space for fitting.

Any idea of why it is happening will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other ones with the same problem I found a solution:

```
<item android:id="@+id/Main_App"
    android:title="Main"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    />

<item android:id="@+id/back_App"
    android:title="Back"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_back"/>
```

I added "android:showAsAction="always|withText" and it worked. Not really sure why is it working, something related with support libraries I guess. Anyway it gives an XML error but it compiles and works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually try displaying only icon without text..because ActionBar allocates some fixed space in it for App Title even though it is small..so in small phones it cant display two icons....and even change order in Category to set the same to both the items..

```
<item android:id="@+id/Main_App"
    android:title="Main"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>

<item android:id="@+id/back_App"
    android:title="Back"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_back"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have been searching deeper and I found what was the matter.
I put android:showAsAction too, it's weird because it gives a XML error but when compilating it goes well and works.

Answer (score 0):

the chosen answer didn't work for me.

In my case when I enter in the activity for the first time the menu items don't show in any fragment. If I rotate the device everything works fine.

[I do not have reputation to add a comment!]